# SimplePie Rss merge to rss output help :[

Tags: php, xml, simplepie

http://pastebin.com/3wAphNpT

http://cal5not.dyndns.tv:8080/DEV/transmission/test4.php

Linked above is my simplepie script, created for the purpose of combining  `rss feeds` and then exportation of the contents as `rss`. unfortunately, I can't seem to get rid of the xml errors. any help would be appreciated
**Update**
Determined that is has to do with the guid field now I just need to figure out how to properly display the guid in the loop

Comment: can u plz elaborate your problem? what issue you are facing to show the rss??

Comment: try subscribing to [link]http://cal5not.dyndns.tv:8080/DEV/transmission/test4.php -  with an rss reader/ you get only one result and the guid value dosnt seem to want to work

Comment: Feed Intent Viewer displays - http://pastebin.com/WACxF1tm

Comment: I determined it has something to do with the <guid></guid> php code

Answer (score 0):

[I did this](http://blog.muschamp.ca/2012/04/27/merging-feeds-with-simplepie-and-php/), documented it, and shared it with the SimplePie developers. It is running live on my website no problems...